# re-try method on error

Tags: java, jcabi

I have the following method which uses a proxy server. The proxy sometimes throws errors and I want the method to re-try on a proxy error. I tried to do this by using the jcabi-aspects library, but it does not seem to be doing what it's supposed to. I don't see any verbose messages on failures. Any help to achieve this is appreciated.

```
@RetryOnFailure(attempts = 2, verbose = true)
public String update(String lastActivityDate)
{
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    try
    {
        String url = "https://api.somesite.com/updates";
        URL urlObj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = null;
        if (useProxy)
        {
            myapp.Proxy proxyCustom = getRandomProxy();
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyCustom.getProxyIp(), proxyCustom.getProxyPort()));
            con = (HttpsURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection(proxy);
        }
        else
        {
            con = (HttpsURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
        }

        // add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("host", urlObj.getHost());
        con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

        String urlParameters = "{}";

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        // System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        // System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        // System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        // print result
        // System.out.println(response.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is happening because you are not supposed to try catch in the method. That annotation: `@RetryOnFailure(attempts = 2, verbose = true)` will execute your method if it throws an exeption. However you are encapsulating all of the code in a `try catch` block.

Looking at the [documentation](http://aspects.jcabi.com/annotation-retryonfailure.html):

> Annotate your methods with @RetryOnFailure annotation and, in case of
>   exception in the method, its execution will be repeated a few times:

Also you might want to add a delay between retries: `@RetryOnFailure(attempts = 2, delay = 2000,  verbose = true)` ( default is in mseconds)

EDIT: if you dont want to configure it to work with jcabi then you can do something like this:

```
int retries = 0;
Boolean success = false; 
while(retries <x && ! success){ // you need to set x depending on how many retries you want
    try{
        // your code goes here
        success = true;
    } 
    catch{
        retries++;
    }
 }
```

Comment: So I would replace the try-catch block with throws Exception at the method? public String update(String lastActivityDate) throws Exception

This should work right?

Comment: @Arya yes, that should do it. Just make sure that the code which uses this method expects an error to be thrown if the function fails 3 times. EDIT: not really sure if it will throw 3 exceptions if all attempts fail or just 1 exception.

Comment: Looks like there is more setup needed then to just adding the jcabi-aspects dependency to pom.xml. From what I read, it sounds like I need to setup binary weaving in order for this to work. Am I right?

Comment: So I guess you went over this [page](http://aspects.jcabi.com/example-weaving.html)? Does it work if you add the 2 dependencies to pom.xml and get the plugin?

Comment: I think it would be just simpler if I code a way to retry, there is too much configuration needed for what I need.

Comment: @Arya Or instead of throwing exception at the method, replace `e.printStackTrace();` with `throw new RuntimeException(e);`

Comment: @Bohemian but then he still needs to make the configuration work.